# keras GRU won't take my simple 2-d arrays

Tags: python, keras

I created a toy dataset which has dim of (n_rows, 51) 50 features and 1 truth. When I do a simple linear regression keras works. Yet once a attempt to use a GRU or LSTM nothing works. Below is an attempt to make this easy on myself. Can someone help me figure out whats wrong.

`

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(50))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Reshape((None, 50)))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=20)
```

`

Comment: GRU layer is used for processing sequence data with shape of `(n_samples, n_timesteps or sequence_length, n_features)`. Your data does not seem to be a sequence data since it has a shape of `(n_samples, n_features)`. Either you need to reformat it to a sequence-like shape or use other suitable layers.

Answer (score 1):

LSTM/GRU needs a 3D array as input.You need to convert your data to an array with 3Dimension ie (samples, timesteps ,features). You can perform the conversion using reshape() function of numpy.
Refer to the [link for how to reshape data for lstm](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/)